# How do I use import my RabbitMQ function into a sveltekit component?

Tags: rabbitmq, sveltekit

I am trying to use RabbitMQ in my sveltekit app. I have a rabbitmq.js file that contains the function to send a message, but when I import it I get the error Buffer is not defined. I have added the following function to add buffer.

```
import { sendEmailTelegram } from '../rabbitmq';

onMount(async () => {
        //import Buffer for rabbitMQ
            const { Buffer } = await import('buffer');
            window.Buffer = Buffer;
        }
```

If I comment the import sendEmailTelegram out and let the page load then uncomment the import the error goes away but then I get a new error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply'), and obviously that would not be a solution anyway because. So what is the proper way to use RabbitMQ in my sveltekit app?